# Dubai airport layover - will I need a visa?

Tags: visas, air-travel, uae

I have to travel from Kolkata to Kazan, Russia via Dubai. Will I need a visa for UAE?

Comment: What is your citizenship?

Answer (score 2):

Emirates, the main airline operating in Dubai [provides a tool for checking visa requirements](http://www.emirates.com/english/plan_book/essential_information/visa_passport_information/find_visa_requirements/find_visa_requirements.aspx).

It indicates visa requirements both for the destination, and for passengers in transit.

For example, an Indian travelling to Russia via the United Arab Emirates (where Dubai is located) says this:

> ## Transit: United Arab Emirates
>
> ### Minors:
>
> Passport not required for minors registered in their parent/guardian passport, provided it contains photos of the minors and traveling with the passport holder.
>
> ### Visa
>
> Visa required.
>
> ### TWOV (Transit Without Visa):
>
> Holders of confirmed onward tickets for a max. transit time of 24 hours.
>   Visa is required for transit between Dubai International Airport (DXB) and Dubai Al Maktoum International (DWC).
>
> ### Visa Issuance:
>
> A 96-hour transit visa can be obtained on arrival at Dubai (DXB), provided:
>   - transit time is at least 8 hours; and
>   - holding onward ticket to a third country; and
>   - holding a passport valid for at least 6 months from date of arrival.
>   Visas are only issued as a part of a transit package together with hotel accommodation and airport transfer (paid by passenger).
>
> ### Minors:
>
> Separate visa not required for minors registered in their parent/guardian passport, provided their name is endorsed in the visa of the parent/guardian.

Which I admit is somewhat unclear. On a flight through Dubai earlier this year, I think I recall there being announcements on the plane and signs at the airport that most EU, North America and gulf states citizens could transit without any visa, but others may need them.